# How to avoid duplication in Makefile targets with similar recipes?

Tags: makefile, dry

I have a Makefile which has a lot of targets and the recipe for each target is quite similar.

```
foo:
    gcc foo.c -o foo
    mv foo ~/bin

bar:
    gcc bar.c -o bar
    mv bar ~/bin

baz:
    gcc baz.c -o baz
    mv baz ~/bin
```

I would like to avoid all this duplication. I would like to have something like below (this is not valid syntax; this only expresses my intention).

```
TARGET_NAME:
    gcc $(TARGET_NAME).c -o $(TARGET_NAME)
    mv $(TARGET_NAME) ~/bin
```

Is it possible to do something like this? If not, what is the best Makefile I can write that can minimize duplication in recipes?

Comment: Like pointed out already elsewhere by @beta, your `Makefile` is broken because you move the files you make so that they will be remade every time, regardless of whether it's necessary.  Also, the `-o` option to `gcc` can eminently take a subdirectory. `bin/%: %.c; gcc $< -o $@`

Answer (score 5):

Your makefile is wrong because your targets (`foo`, `bar`, etc.) don't depend on their source files (`foo` doesn't depend on `foo.c`, etc.)  So, changing the source code won't cause the target to be rebuilt.

Also, your makefile says you're creating a file `foo`, but your recipe actually creates a file `~/bin/foo`, which is not the same thing.

Anyway, this is exactly what [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) are for:

```
EXES = foo bar baz

all: $(addprefix $(HOME)/bin/,$(EXES))

$(HOME)/bin/%:: %.c
        gcc $< -o $@
```

(Thanks to Beta for pointing out my think-o in the original)

Comment: Aren't you violating one of [your own rules](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/)? Number 2 of 6, to be precise: the target pattern should match the actual name of the thing being built (`~/bin/%`).

Comment: You should use [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) to avoid using [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-versus-Implicit.html). Something like that: `foo bar baz: %: %.c`

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking it was a `cp` not a `mv`.  I'll update.  Regarding "static pattern rules": I see this advice all the time that you "should" use them.  I virtually never use them.  In fact I always use normal pattern rules and ONLY use static pattern rules when I have a subset of targets that should be built a different way.  I think it's a style/opinion thing; I wouldn't tell people they "should" use them without any justification.

Answer (score 3):

A `make` rule can actually match multiple targets:

```
foo bar baz:
    gcc $@.c -o $@
    mv $@ ~/bin
```

However, you should make the dependencies explicit in the rules:

```
foo: foo.c
bar: bar.c
baz: baz.c

foo bar baz:
    gcc $< -o $@
    mv $@ ~/bin
```

The first three lines only specifiy the dependencies without any actions to actually build them. You can generate these with the help of gcc: `gcc -MM foo.c` will print a rule for `foo.c`.